# How can I perform an arbitrary search in the Xbox YouTube app?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, youtube

Admittedly I haven't played with the Xbox YouTube app much. I looked through various tabs and menus and could not find a way to perform a keyword search. Is there a way?

Comment: @Juan, How is this off-topic?  [You apparently agree with me](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96/6066) that console use questions are on-topic, and I think this falls squarely there -- using an app on a gaming machine.

Comment: I think this fits the FAQ, the original title just seemed too specific. IMO how to use the console's apps are problems gamers face, unless we want to say it's a Super User thing...but I think G.SE remains the better source even for app use on consoles.

Comment: Sorry, yes I see my original title was trying to be a little too cute.  The edit captures my goal perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current incarnation (March 2012), hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to be presented with the search interface (it's displayed at the bottom left-hand corner of the screen). You can use the controller to enter a search query, or use gestures to select characters with Kinect. It does not currently have support for voice control through the Kinect.